# ValidationRule is firing when i hit cancel button

Tags: wpf, xaml, validationrules

I have a data grid with some items and validation rule that is checking if item's in grid are correct.

There is also a close button and the problem is when you click it validator is checking if added value are correct and if not it's prompting an error but I just want to close the window and skip validating the data.

The reason for that is when you click cancel button you also lose focus which trigger validation

Code should explain it better:

```
<DataGrid  Name="MyGrid" Loaded="GetSth" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                    <configuration:SomeCoolValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
                </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>

                      <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <!-- some columns  -->
                      </DataGrid.Columns>

                <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Close" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="CloseClick"/>      
  </DataGrid>
```

And code behind:

```
  <!-- Code behind -->
  private void CloseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
            <!-- When clicked i just want window to close, not to check validator rules -->
            Close(); 

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set focusable property on button to false.

This way you don't change datagrid itemsSource when clicking close button and validator isn't starting.